# im new to SQL and i cant seem to find why do i get this error ( missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

this is the table I am trying to create but I get this error

> Error at line 7/34: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833 ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903

5. quantity INT NOT NULL,
6. list_price DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL,
7. discount DECIMAL (4, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
8. PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
9. FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id),"

This is the code:

```
 CREATE TABLE order_items (
    order_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    list_price DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
    discount DECIMAL(4 , 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id , item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
        REFERENCES orders (order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES products (product_id)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

With constraints, `default` goes first, `not null` next (see line #7):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE order_items (
  2      order_id   INT,
  3      item_id    INT,
  4      product_id INT NOT NULL,
  5      quantity   INT NOT NULL,
  6      list_price DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  7      discount   DECIMAL(4, 2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,   --> here
  8     PRIMARY KEY ( ORDER_ID , ITEM_ID ) ,
  9     FOREIGN KEY ( ORDER_ID ) REFERENCES ORDERS ( ORDER_ID ) ,
 10     FOREIGN KEY ( PRODUCT_ID ) REFERENCES PRODUCTS ( PRODUCT_ID ));

Table created.

SQL>
```